# Sorted tree with links for next and previous nodes

Tags: dictionary, tree, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Imagine a usual binary search tree with ordered keys, where each node also has a link for next (the leftmost node in right child) and previous (the rightmost node in left child) nodes. How such a data structure is called (if there is a name for it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a special case of [threaded binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree#Types_of_threaded_binary_trees), with the binary tree itself is binary search tree.

One type of threaded binary tree is called "Double threaded binary tree": each node is threaded towards both the in-order predecessor and successor (left and right).

In you case for binary search tree, the rightmost node in left child is actually the in-order predecessor and the leftmost node in right child is actually the in-order successor.

Comment: Was looking exactly for that! Thank you.